# PHP making a string useable but not readable

Tags: php

So I am not sure if this is possible,but here we go. I want to be able to create a string that functions as normal ,but is not readable. For example:

```
$password = "//312(!@#()";
```

then I could go something like.

```
if($input == $password) {

}
```

Is there anyway I can possibly do this? I may be talking through a hole in my head, but any help on the subject would help.

Comment: can u define more on not "readable"?

Comment: Do you mean not readable to PHP? That's not possible. However if you were to add control characters, that's difficult to render on-screen, though also difficult to enter as characters on a keyboard! Maybe if you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve, someone can advise you.

Comment: Are you talking about password hashing? http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: You asked this question badly, but as @FAngel hints - this is why hashing algorithms are used. You create a hash of your password and you get a digest. You use the digest, and even if someone finds out what the digest is - they don't know the original string where it came from.

Comment: @FAngel makes a good point - and look up "salting" as well.

Comment: I mean that it is not readable to human eye, but readable to php.

Comment: @FAngel hasing password is one way only :) 
Duncan: If someone can get your PHP code, you will not able to hide anything from them :D

Comment: @DuncanPalmer - but if it is readable to PHP then it can be _made_ human readable.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: Theoretically you can encrypt it and store *that* password in another file. But what have you gained?

Comment: I have seen some php source files that use the 'eval' function I believe and the code is all // and letters + numbers.

Comment: dude if you want your password to be safe than simply use the encode function

Comment: yes, eval and base64_encode, base64_decoe, but they can always decode your string to get the original source. PHP source code can not be bidden like ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

You can hash the String:

```
$pw_hash = "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6" //is the hash of "test"

if ($pw_hash == md5($variable)){
    //now you know, the variable is "test", 
    //without writing it plaintext in the sourcecode.
}
```

But search for hashes. There are better options than md5. Also google for "salt" and get aware of what's the difference between "hashing" and "encrypting".

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I believe that you want to hide your php source code when deploy the application. I see many developer usually use the `base64_encode` encode the original PHP code to be a single string and use `eval(base64_decode($str))` in their deployed package.

However, that way can only useful with normal user, we can always use an online tool like http://perishablepress.com/tools/decoder/ (or write your own function) to get the original source :)